# How to redirect all links with specified subdomain to its root domain

Tags: regex, redirect, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I need help with writing a URL Redirect rule on IIS 7.5

I need to create a rule so if someone visits the site `this-sub.example.com/anything` then he would be redirected to the `example.com` page.

```
<rule name="My redirection home">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^this-sub.example.com/*.*" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

instead of redirecting `this-sub.example.com/anything` to `example.com` it redirects to `example.com/anything`. It keeps the `anything` part. I have also URL Rewrite module installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule will redirect everything from `this-sub.example.com` to `example.com`

```
<rule name="My redirection home" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^this-sub\." />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thank you, its the solution for me.